# Android Downloading SDK from eclipse get Read Timed Out Nothing installed

Tags: android

Tried this from starbucks Att&T network, now panera.  Slow networks but Read Timed Out?  What the %$^#$& is this?

Failed to fetch URL http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml/addon.xml, reason: Read timed out
Failed to fetch URL http://developer.lgmobile.com/sdk/android/repository.xml/addon.xml, reason: File not found

Comment: Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 5
Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

I recently happened such a situation, poydock of action that helped me: in the SDK Manager first select and install the Android SDK Platform-tools, and only then install other required packages.